# LUA 5.4.0 live demo isn't consistent with binary

Tags: lua

I downloaded the latest binary for Windows of LUA 5.4.0, through [the official source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.4.0/Tools%20Executables/).

When using the [live demo](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) if I write the following code :

```
print(string.byte("§",1))
print(string.byte("§",2))
```

It returns

```
194 
167
```

However, if I use the windows binary :

```
PS C:\Users\200207121> lua54
Lua 5.4.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2020 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(string.byte("§",1)); print(string.byte("§",2))
```

It returns

```
245

>
```

Both the live demo and my installation use LUA 5.4.0.
There is no other LUA libraries installed on my system.

**Why do the outputs differ ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

§ (U+00A7) is a non-ASCII character, thus its encoding can differ between platforms.

There is no difference between the binaries; the web version simply uses UTF-8 for input. Lua strings are encoding-agnostic, so it will simply treat the characters you input as bytes (0xC2 0xA7).

Your terminal where you run Lua uses an old (single-byte) OEM code page, where § is 0xF5, hence the single byte. Lua again simply treats your input as bytes, and it only displays what you enter.

This has been true for all Lua versions.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't even try to run it locally by writing it in a .lua file, and indeed it outputs the same thing as the live demo. Weird though that Powershell, standard CMD, Terminal and MinGW all have the same code page (which outputs an 'unexpected' result).

Comment: @ArthurAttout The backwards compatibility of the Windows console. You can use `chcp` to change the used codepage to something common.